# UIViewController not popping to root?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

**Some details:**

`InitialController` is the storyboard entry point. There I check if i'm logged in and perform a segue to main app page, or if i'm not then I perform a segue to login controller.

I.e. in `InitialController` (which is a `UINavigationController`) I have

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([already logged in]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMain" sender:self];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toLogin" sender:self];
    }
}
```

If I go the login route I get to a point where my view controller looks like this (using the internal _printHierarchy method)

```
<InitialController 0x7fbdfc81c200>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fbdfa3b8910>
   | <LoginController 0x7fbdfa01be50>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x7fbdf9631670> not in the window
   | <AnotherController 0x7fbdfe286e00>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fbdfe12b680>
```

When I finish the action on `AnotherController` I call popToRootViewController... this annoyingly takes me to `LoginController` but I attempted to work around this by adding this method to the `LoginController`

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (...) { // is only true when I want it to be true
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

I set up a breakpoint that prints the hierarchy again just before I call this popToRoot method... and I get:

```
<InitialController 0x7fbdfc81c200>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x7fbdfa3b8910>
   | <LoginController 0x7fbdfa01be50>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fbdf9631670>
```

But it stays on the `LoginController` despite the fact I want to go back to `InitialController`. Why isn't it letting me go back to the `InitialController`?
I'm guessing this might have to do with the fact they're both appeared so maybe the `LoginController` is somehow treated as the root or something to do with the `UILayoutContainerView`?

**Side note:** I also tried not making the `InitialController` a `UINavigationController` and the view hierarchy then becomes:

```
<InitialController 0x7fcddac9da30>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x7fcddb35e500> not in the window
   + <LoginController 0x7fcddaf02eb0>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x7fcddb3635a0>, presented with: <_UIFullscreenPresentationController 0x7fcddb103700>
```

which again doesn't allow me to pop to the `InitialController` either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UINavigationController is a container that manages a stack of viewControllers (which does not include itself). The rootViewController of the UINavigationController is the first viewController in that stack, so that is what popToRootViewControllerAnimated: will direct you to.
You should not be putting your content directly into a UINavigationController.

My recommendation is to have the storyboard entry point be a separate UINavigationController that then contains the InitialController as the first viewController in it's stack (which should be a UIViewController, not a UINavigationController). Then when you call popToRootViewControllerAnimated: on the UINavigationController you will be taken to the InitialController.

Comment: yep turns out a UINavigationController can't be it's own stand alone root. Didn't know that thanks